# How to add other file types to AWstats's "Downloaded" section?

Tags: awstats

Currently, the "Downloaded" section of my AWstats does not report downloaded DjVu files; however, the "File typs" section does count how many DjVu files have been accessed. What do I need to add to `awstats.conf` to get DjVu or other file-types to appear in the "Downloaded" section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your file extention in section NotPageList